# How to repeat the last run script in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

If I run a script, is there a way to run it again without doing `File|Scripts|My_script`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an **action**, assign an F-key to the action, then use the F-key.

Use the **`Insert Menu Item`** command located in the **Action Panel Menu** to insert the call to the script.

But be aware, when you quit Illustrator, the action loses the connection to the script. So, each time you launch Illustrator, you have reconfigure the action. This is a long standing bug in Illustrator.

Comment: I can't even get scripts to show up under actions when I'm recording. How do you do that?

Comment: @Johannes You have to use the "Insert Menu Item" option in the Action Panel menu.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the answer is **no**. This has been a requested feature for years now and Adobe has done nothing to address it.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> gets you into the Open Scripts dialog (in Windows, anyways)...It's not an answer to your question but I sometimes find it to be quicker than clicking File and going to Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows I use [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org//) for things like this.

Example:

To use <kbd>F1</kbd> to run File > Scripts > Script Name it would look like this...

```
F1::Send !frs
```

Edit: I forgot to mention if you want this shortcut to be Illustrator specific so it doesn't affect any other programs just add the following...

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Illustrator.exe
F1::Send !frs
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: I just put the path to my script there, and it will execute the script file in the appropriate application, as long as within that script the #target directive is used: `#target illustrator`

Answer (score -2):

I think <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>＋<kbd>D</kbd> can do it. I practiced it with general actions in AI and other scripts.